# Knockout - keyCode property not being passed through wrapped function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dom-events, keycode, function-literal

I've set up my Knockout bindings to have a keypress event because I wish to detect <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an input field.

If I have the following:

```
data-bind="event: { keypress: KeyPress }"
```

and my view-model has

```
this.KeyPress = function(data, event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
}
```

then the keyCode shows up as expected.

However, I wish to pass an additional parameter to the function `KeyPress`, so following the example from [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html), I now have

```
data-bind="event: { keypress: function (data, event) { KeyPress('myParam', data, event); return true; } }" />
```

and my corresponding function now becomes

```
this.KeyPress = function(p, data, event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
}
```

Now, the `keyCode` property always returns 0. I can see inside the `event` object that the `charCode` property is being set for each key-press, but not the `keyCode` property (and the `charCode` property isn't much use because all non-printable characters are 0).

I can also see that the `event` object has an `originalEvent` property, but the `keyCode` in here is the same, *i.e.* 0.

So can anyone tell me how to get the `keyCode` property propagating through the function literal?

[Here is a JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajameson/r3t9D/) demonstrating it.

Comment: are you using **FireFox** ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you get this result `0` only in firefox

so change your code into this:

```
this.KeyPress = function(p, data, event) {
    console.log(window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which);
}
```